# How do you colloquially express "Who am I to decide who you date?" in French?

Tags: expressions

The expression "**who am I to + infinitive**" is a rhetorical device with the meaning of:

> « je ne suis pas le mieux placé pour décider ... »
>
> or « ce n'est pas à moi qu'il revient de décider ... »,

though with a more light-hearted or nonchalant tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation for this is nearly literal in French. We would say, the same way as in English:

> Qui suis-je pour décider avec qui tu sors?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that possibility, too! Though as it was too word-for-word, I wasn't sure. Merci.

Comment: Can you also say "Qui es-tu pour décider avec qui je sors !" Merci.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee It's indeed working both way. If you disagree with the fact that someone can say such a thing to you, you can answer "Qui es-tu pour...", as you just said.

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention: How about "Qui est-il pour décider ...", then?

Comment: @Ahalone-zee This formulation is working with any person. So yes!

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

> *De quel droit déciderais-je avec qui tu sors ?* (formal)
>
> *De quel droit je déciderais/choisirais avec qui tu sors ?* (colloquial)

or

> *Ce n'est pas à moi de décider avec qui tu sors.*

If you want to stick to the English structure, as Isuka already suggested, the following sentence is possible, while a little formal for the light-hearted and nonchalant tone you asked for :

> *Qui suis-je pour décider avec qui tu sors ?*

Comment: Hi. Do the "de quel droit" construction serve as a rhetorical question? If so, can you also say "De quel droit tu décides avec qui je sors !" In the case of "tu", I suppose it is better to use the present indicative?

Comment: Yes, *de quel droit* serves as a rhetorical question. *De quel droit tu décides avec qui je sort !* is possible but there is no "light-hearted or nonchalant tone" here, this is on the opposite an argument starting point.